Typo3 multidomain multilanguage preview-problem of hidden sites
I have a multidomain, multilanguage Setup with four domains like this:
www.domain-a.de
www.domain-a.com
www.domain-b.de
www.domain-b.com
Running on Typo3 v11.5.36
where the 'com' for the english version and the 'de' for the german version
works fine - "small" problem here is that the backend user can't preview hidden sites of other domains.
An other issues is that this is also true for the english domains ... so they cant preview the translated sites :(
It results in a 404-Site (the 404-Site which we have configured)
I created some starting points in the  Site-Administration but this works just for one domain (and is not bi-directional works for a -> b but not b -> a (ok better then nth)) but not for the english ones.
The backend users have to "enable" the site they want to preview.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

The cause of the issue is that you have multiple toplevel hosts which cannot share sessions of TYPO3 BE users. If one logs into the TYPO3 BE at www.domain-a.de/typo3 this does not have any effect on the other hosts. And you need an active BE session for additional permissions like viewing disabled pages.
One solution which would work without any changes is logging in into the TYPO3 backend for each host you want to work with. For the given example this would require editors to log into the TYPO3 backend 4 times, once for each host. In this case there would be 4 active BE sessions which would allow you to view hidden pages within each site.
There is no easy solution for this beyond that since you need at least a base host shared between the single BE and the multiple FE sites E.g. if all FE sites would live on subdomains instead, then you could configure the BE cookie domain accordingly. However, this does not work for multiple toplevel domains. You could try wapplersystems/multisite-belogin but this requires TYPO3v12.

thanks for the quick reply! i'll test the extension. it's also available for the 11s in the TER. i'll let you know as soon as i've added it :) thanks
